# SQL Server difference between two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

This is my table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQTfc.jpg)

I have a problem I don't understand the difference between the following two queries:

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    productID,
    SUM(soldQty)
FROM
    Sales
WHERE
    soldQty <> 0
GROUP BY  
    ProductID
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT
    productID,
    SUM(soldQty)
FROM
    Sales
GROUP BY 
    ProductID
HAVING
    SUM(soldQty) <> 0
```

Which `productID`'s will result in the queries? Isn't it the same?

Comment: The queries **are** semantically different, but your source data hides that difference. Whereas if you had any rows with `SoldQty = -1` you would see different results.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: A HAVING filter is performed after aggregation is done (logically, not necessarily physically), so rows like: -6 + 6 won't be filtered in the WHERE, but they will get filtered in the HAVING

Answer (score 3):

The queries are *not* the same. The first query will `SUM` rows where the value of `soldQty` is not equal to `0`.

The *second* query, however, will return rows where the *`SUM`* of the values in `soldQty` do not *total* `0`. As a result if the `SUM` of the values comes to `0`, such as `10`, `-4` and `-6` those rows would be omitted. This would not be the case for the first query.

```sql
SELECT MyColumn,
       SUM(IntColumn) AS TotalIntColumn
FROM (VALUES(1,0),
            (1,2),
            (1,5),
            (1,0),
            (1,-2),
            (2,10),
            (2,-4),
            (2,-6),
            (2,0),
            (3,0))V(MyColumn,IntColumn)
WHERE IntColumn <> 0
GROUP BY MyColumn;

SELECT MyColumn,
       SUM(IntColumn) AS TotalIntColumn
FROM (VALUES(1,0),
            (1,2),
            (1,5),
            (1,0),
            (1,-2),
            (2,10),
            (2,-4),
            (2,-6),
            (2,0),
            (3,0))V(MyColumn,IntColumn)
GROUP BY MyColumn
HAVING SUM(IntColumn) <> 0;
```

Notice that `2` is returned in the first dataset, with a value of `0` for `TotalIntColumn`, but it is not returned in the second. Neither result set return a row with a value of `3` for `MyColumn` as `IntColumn` only contains the value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 will omit all records, regardless of productid, having a soldQty <> 0

Query 2 will omit all records associated with all products having a cumulative sum soldQty <> 0